# Access word document context from dialog with Office JS Word API

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, office365api, office365-apps

I am trying to access the word document context from a dialog, like so:

```js
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync("Hello World!",
        function (asyncResult) {
            var error = asyncResult.error;
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                 write(error.name + ": " + error.message);
            }
        });
```

This does not work as setSelectedDataAsync is undefined.

In the documentation here https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync it says at the bottom under **Design considerations** "Do not use a dialog box to interact with a document. Use a task pane instead."

Is it not possible at all to access the **complete** word document context from a dialog or is it just a recommendation to not do it?

Ideally I would like to show the user a list of entries with a lot of details, from which the user then can select one and a document will be inserted into the document. Technically I could do this in a TaskPane, but there is limited space there. If possible at all I would really like to do it in a dialog (especially as I have a few other very similar requirements).

Any chance to interact with the word document in the same way as from as TaskPane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't interact with the document from a dialog.

From the documentation:

https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

> The *messageParent* function is one of only two Office APIs that can be called in the dialog box. (The other is Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported)

So basically, all you can do from a dialog is show/collect some data and send it back to the parent via the `messageParent` function.

You can display all the options to the user, then send back the selected one to the parent window, and there interact with the document as required.

Comment: I almost assumed I would have to implement it like that, good suggestion!